# Openshift unsecure versions of Apache httpd

Tags: python, apache, openshift

I am evaluating Openshift Online PaaS and found that Openahift Online is using quite old versions of libraries, which might bring issues.

Eg. Apache httpd - version 2.2.15 as of today (2014-04-27) vs published 2.2.27 with several SECURITY fixes in changelog

Can Redhat explain the difference?

Concrete issue for python cartridge and connectivity to PostgreSQL: psycopg2 - Openshift default is the older 2.0.4 version throwing errors, while the newest one is ==2.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenShift Online runs based on RHEL 6, and the versions there need a little explanation. RHEL is based on the premise that if you run something on RHEL 6.0 GA, it should still run after years of updates to RHEL 6. There are still updates, but the version indicates where the original fork of the code was done. New features are introduced (only if they break nothing old), and security patches are added, but these are done with changes to the *release* number, not the version. If you look for security advisories from Red Hat, you will see this in action, e.g. https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2014-0370.html. It can be confusing to determine exactly what features are included; for instance RHEL 5 ships httpd 2.2.3, but includes a bunch of mod_proxy features that didn't land until 2.2.9 or later.

Recently, Red Hat, in recognition that people don't necessarily want to develop against years-old solutions, has begun supplying updated versions in completely separate packages as Software Collections Libraries (SCLs). For example, the postgresql that ships with RHEL 6 is version 8.4, but an SCL has been shipped with postgresql 9.2 (OpenShift Online supplies a cartridge for both). An SCL for httpd 2.4 should be coming soon.

Point is, the apparent version can be a little deceiving on RHEL; it basically indicates "compatible with behavior back to this version." To get to the root of your real problem, it's probably best to specify what you're doing and the actual errors you got.

Comment: OK, I understand the statement, but am not sure whether it makes easier to know what features and sec fixes have been applied to the forked versions.

Comment: Also I am not sure the explanation is applicable to the mentioned psycopg2 library.

Comment: I have to admit to being fairly clueless about python. Note that Openshift Online has three versions, though, and they each have separate executables (2.6 is from the base OS, 2.7 and 3.3 are from an SCL). Could be you're seeing something from a different version. How did you determine your module version? I just created a python 3.3 app and the python3 interpreter and pkg_resources.get_distribution("psycopg2").version returns '2.5.1'.

Comment: To list the versions of Python packages - login via ssh and enter 'pip list'

The issue was detected with Python 2.6 libraries.

Comment: Thanks. "pip show psycopg2" on a python 2.6 gear indicates Location: /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages - it's coming right out of the system libraries, with versions frozen in time at RHEL 6 GA - security fixes applied, perhaps other updates, but largely untouched. You get a different pip, and a different set of libraries, with a python-2.7 or -3.3 gear based on a python SCL (SCLs are maintained similarly as RHEL, they just fork different versions to begin with). That hopefully explains the versions, if not your problem.

Comment: BTW if you believe the package version to be an issue, you should be able to choose the version you want with requirements.txt... this is a relatively new ability (https://www.openshift.com/blogs/openshift-online-march-2014-release-blog), used to need to do it with setup.py